# SELECT from query results

Tags: sql, select

I'm completely new to SQL, and have no experience of it what so ever.

I have this query:

```
SELECT item FROM character_inventory WHERE guid = 6 AND slot <= 38
```

This works as intended, and returns all the items.
I would now like to select the results, and use them in a second query, where I select from another table but with the results from this query, how do I accomplish this?

Comment: use this query as inner query. read more about inner query in sql

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with the subquery or nested query.

Example :

```
select * from table where item in (SELECT item FROM character_inventory WHERE guid = 6 AND slot <= 38)
```